# Resolve path of Excel

Tags: c#, windows, excel, .net-3.5, path

Actually I intended to ask the following question:

> For an executable that lies in a
>   directory defined in `%PATH%`, how can
>   I find out in which of these directory
>   it is found?

because I need to run Excel from C# using Process.Run(...), and just indicating "Excel" works fine: Windows seems to know where to find it. However I need to provide the appropriate working directory, too.

**But in the meantime** I found out that Microsoft Office is not even in the %PATH%, Windows apparently resolves it in another way.

So how could I use or mimic this functionality from Windows to get the directory containing excel?

**Update:** Besides the suggestion of Ruel, **is there a straighter way to achieve this**? I know that Windows is able to resolve the path in some way, so I'd like to reuse this functionality if possible.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch it from the registry: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\(VERSION)\Excel\InstallRoot` for the `VERSION` it can be 10.0 11.0 etc. You can detect it by checking if there's a subkey `Excel` in it.

Comment: On Windows x64, it will be in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\Excel\InstallRoot`