# How to get the path of the installed Excel.exe programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows, process

Is there any way that I could find a way to retrieve the path of the Excel executable file in C# or VB.Net? I'm aware of these two options below, but unfortunately they are not suitable. Please suggest if you have an alternative.

1. Using the Registry
2. Using `Process.Start("Excel")` and getting the path from the Excel process

Cannot use the Registry option because people without sufficient rights may be using my application and hence we wanted to stay away. If this assumption is wrong and Registry is reliable for any level of user access rights, please let me know.

With Second option, I'm seeing the Excel process being opened, if there is a way where I can start, but not have Excel process appear at all to the user, this may work.

Comment: Directory crawl then?  Its pretty much the only option left, and its slow, and has more errors.  But the registry approach is more suitable, everyone would have read access which is all you need.

Comment: Using registry: http://visualbasic.about.com/od/quicktips/qt/regprogpath.htm or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831028/resolve-path-of-excel

Comment: Why do you want to know the path of the EXE? What do you need it for? I ask because I do all kinds of stuff with excel and have never needed the full path.

Comment: Steve, I need the path of EXE so that I can extract the installed version's Icon. Is there any other easy way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up with this logic and it serves my purpose. If Excel is a running process, then I'm getting the path from there, if not I'm getting by creating an instance, which doesn't actually show the Excel UI, but runs in the background.

```
            string path = string.Empty;

            Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
            {
                if (theprocess.ProcessName == "EXCEL")
                {
                    path = theprocess.MainModule.FileName;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (path == string.Empty)
            {
                Type officeType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
                dynamic xlApp = Activator.CreateInstance(officeType);
                xlApp.Visible = false;
                path = xlApp.Path + @"\Excel.exe";
                xlApp.Quit();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start it hidden and close it. You would have to include the interop services for the below code

```
    Dim xl As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
    xl.Visible = False
    Dim Excel_Path As String = xl.Path()
    xl.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check at this [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start)

You can start the process hidden, so the user will not see the window

```
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```